# Adding a property to an element according to a condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, ternary

I'm looking for the safest way of doing this:

I have a property with two possible values a `string` and `null`
Let's suppose we have a `var` which takes `str = 'a string'` or `null`

I want to cast it to `boolean` for enabling or disabling a button.

I wrote `disabled={Boolean(str)}` but I read that this is not the safest way.

I want to do this with a ternary operator.

Any ideas?

Comment: `!!str` would be safe and elegant.

Comment: What is your definition of "cast it to a boolean" because that will change the answer? Do you mean you want to convert a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value to `true`?